# How to make 2 UIImageView Over another UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

[image]
[image]

Background there 1 imageview like tShirt and upper we can put sticker or another image but we zoom the 2nd image that are cover only background image

If i zoom photo of men it should be cover only tshirt image and another portion are transparent alpha less than 1 How it possible?

Comment: If i zoom photo of men it should be cover only tshirt image and another portion are transparent alpha less than 1

How it possible?

Comment: Hello Badal can you have logic about my Q?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the imageview inside a scrollview and can use Scrollview delegate for zooming in: (simply when zooming in you can resize the image so only the shirt will be available on the screen)

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
     return self.imageView;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.5;
     self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=6.0;
     self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1280, 960);
     self.scrollView.delegate=self;
}
```

Comment: Not need to Zoom the Image. there are 2 imageview 1 is tShirt and another is men photo. if i zoom the men photo then it should be men photo's uiimageview alpha is 1 and out side the tshirt the men photo alpha is 0.5